# Cumulative count where key equals value from another column in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I am trying to compile cumulative count for each **team** in my DataFrame where **team** = **df['result'] == 'W'**.
'W' stands for win, therefore I am trying to calculate how many games each team won prior to the next game. This is my code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'team': ['Inter', 'Barca', 'Psv', 'Totten', 'Psv', 'Barca', 'Inter', 'Totten', 'Totten', 'Psv', 'Inter', 'Barca'],
'result': ['W', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'W', 'D', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'D', 'D']
})

df['each_played'] = df.groupby('team').cumcount()
df['each_won'] = ???
print(df)
```

I have successfully calculated how many games each team played prior to the game, but can't get it to work for df['each_won'].

Desired Output:

```
     team       result       each_played    each_won
0    Inter      W            0              0
1    Barca      W            0              0
2      Psv      L            0              0
3   Totten      L            0              0
4      Psv      D            1              0
5    Barca      W            1              1
6    Inter      D            1              1
7   Totten      W            1              0
8   Totten      W            2              1
9      Psv      L            2              0
10   Inter      D            2              1
11   Barca      D            2              2
```

I am quite new to pandas, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second problem is a `cumsum` problem. You will need `shift` and `cumsum` inside a `GroupBy.apply` call.

```
df['each_won'] = (df.result
                    .eq('W')
                    .groupby(df.team)
                    .apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
                    .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))
df
      team result  each_played each_won
0    Inter      W            0        0
1    Barca      W            0        0
2      Psv      L            0        0
3   Totten      L            0        0
4      Psv      D            1        0
5    Barca      W            1        1
6    Inter      D            1        1
7   Totten      W            1        0
8   Totten      W            2        1
9      Psv      L            2        0
10   Inter      D            2        1
11   Barca      D            2        2
```